# Is creating a custom TabBar against apple policies?

Tags: ios, policy

Here's a quick question.

Does apple have any kind of policies against creating custom behaviour for a TabBar ? For example, I'm not happy with the default behaviour for the TabBar and I would like to create one myself as a custom view that will always be on the bottom, then I will add whatever functionality I need to.

Is there anything from apple against this when publishing apps ?

PS: I searched on google and couldn't find anything, just rumours.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apple likes your app to look as native as possible. So do most of the users. Or so i'm told. So i would say it is not advisable in the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on apps before that have used custom tab bars and there has not been an issue with the app store, there are also lots of open source tab bars produced by others as well, so they would not waste their effort on things that can't be used.

But I would stress that people expect certain user interface elements to behave in certain ways and they are used to the standard tabbar. So using the default is probably the best way to go, it also ensures it covers multiple tabbar scenarios, so I would at least consider subclassing and calling super where appropriate.

Comment: The problem is that I need 2 different behaviours for the "More" tab one of which is the default. The other is that when you click it from another tab, there should be a popover with the "More" options and the "More" icon should become active as long as the popover is on top of the current tab (so the previous view controller must still be active along with the new "More" view controller). I'm new to this, but I couldn't do anything like this. TabBar switches view controllers to make a tab bar icon active, I found no workaround for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the UITabBarController delegate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate you can check what item they have tapped and perform additional code

Comment: I just tried to make a tab 'fake active' and I couldn't do it, without the view controllers being switched. By fake active I mean, highlighting another tab as being active, while keeping the old one. I'll take a look more, but I'm skeptical on this.

Comment: The problem is that I just want to highlight another tab as being active, without anything else to change from the TabBar. Just the icon being highlighted as active.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing official about apple preventing such a thing.

I worked on application where we had almost an Android behavior application, and we had no problem what so ever with Apple.

This is not a strict to the TabBar nor any other custom components.

But be careful when you custom things, sometimes you custom something and instead of making it prettier or better it turns out to be worst. Apple however would prefer the application to look native as possible.

Comment: Yes I know Tobi, but I have the exact specifications for the app in questions. And I can't seem to find any workarounds using the default TabBar. I have literally no choice.

Comment: well go for it then, nothing can prevent you from doing what you have to do. at the end we always have to custom something whether its tabBar or something else, i just wanted to point out those stuff, and that there is nothing official preventing that

Answer (score 0):

> Does apple have any kind of policies against creating custom behaviour
>   for a TabBar ?

No, it would not lead to let your app to be rejected. **However**, Apple recommends that your app should be native as much as possible, by following the guidelines for creating an app, which means that it follows the iOS apps default experience.

Keep in mind that mentioning:

> I'm not happy with the default behaviour for the TabBar

might cause to your app a user experience issue. From an end user perspective, the default behavior for the tab bar *is* the behavior that should be applied, it doesn't has to be changed because that's the expectation when dealing with a tab bar.

Nevertheless, when it comes to playing around some minor animation -for instance- it might be a not bad idea; At least try to not change the core behaviors.

---

**Furthermore:**

You might want to check Apple [Human Interface Guidelines - Tab Bars](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/).